# Extracting a table name after installing a extension module in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

So the thing is I am developing a contrib module and want to capture table name inside that contrib module.

question:

1. Is there any way to capture a table name during create table or insert table?
   I have seen some of the triggers but not able to make it (I don't think there is any create table trigger). In case it is possible tell me a way to achieve it.
2. I though of extracting meta-data using pg_class but not helping it seems because I have to give explicitly a  rel-name (table name) in where clause 
   do you think any other way to achieve it? Please elaborate if any and please let me know.

Here is some example which will make you understand a bit about the things I want to achieve.

creating a table:

```
create table new_table(name varchar , new integer);  
insert into new_table values('abcdefghijkl' , 5004);
create table new_table1(name1 varchar , new1 integer) ;
 insert into new_table1 values('mnopqrst' , 5005);
```

creating extension:

```
create extension table_name-extract;
select extract_tablename();
```

So my extension should extract a table name, means I should know table name with the built-in datatype I have declared.

Here what I expect as a output:

```
select extract_tablename();

table-name      datatype-name
new_table       name    new
new_table1      name1   new1
```

Comment: What is a "cont-rib module"? Whats the need of grabbing the name of a newly created table?

Comment: @Nico contrib modules are the module which any developer can install or develop explicitly in order to achieve extra functionalities and i want to use those information for my own need

Comment: To capture a `CREATE TABLE` statement you can use an [event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-trigger-definition.html)

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve: do you want to track the tables that your extension creates (which would not be necessary as `create extension` already does that)? Or do you want to track _any_ table creation in the database?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes ,I mean i need a information about table name whenever user creates some specific table ,i want to track those kind of table in my extension.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need an extension to track the execution of DDL statements.

For that you can use an [event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-trigger-definition.html)

The manual also has [an example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-EVENT-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE) on how to write an event trigger using PL/pgSQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION snitch() 
  RETURNS event_trigger 
AS $$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'snitch: % %', tg_event, tg_tag;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER snitch ON ddl_command_start 
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE snitch();
```

Inside the trigger function you would need to store the table name in some configuration table so that the information is not lost.

Of course you can package your trigger and "log table" (as a [configuration table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-extensions.html#EXTEND-EXTENSIONS-CONFIG-TABLES)) into an extension if you want.

---

Another option is to enable [DDL logging](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT) using

```
log_statement=ddl
```

in `postgresql.conf` - then you have all DDL statements in the Postgres logfile.